# I am trying to take screenshot after every verification method and after that all screenshot should save in final test result (.index)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

In java selenium i have to Take multiple screenshot and save all them in final result

I have tried calling screenshot method like take screenshot and save into specific folder also i have tried ExtentReports classes but project not allowed me to add jar file so it not working for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.